# How to open a file in android with qt having the content URI

Tags: android, qt, qfiledialog, qfile, qtandroidextras

How do i open a file with QFile with link in android  -content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw.pdf

I tried below code but its showing that the file not open

```
 QString path("content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw.pdf");
 QUrl path_url(path);
 path = path_url.toLocalFile();
 QFile* file = new QFile(path);
 file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)
```

Comment: You should try to open an input stream to read the file. Like InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);

Comment: Is this through Qt?

Comment: Hey, @HusniAbdulNazer did you resolve the problem? I am facing it too right now!

Answer (score 1):

**QQmlFile** could format it to /storage/emulated/0/....

QString path("content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw.pdf");
QUrl url(path);

```
QFile file(QQmlFile::urlToLocalFileOrQrc(url));
  if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    emit error(tr("Could not open file. '%1'").arg(file.errorString()));
    return;
  }
```

[example](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75484) for detail implementation.